# Prometheus TimeStamp with too many characters

Tags: go, prometheus

I am using the go remote writer here: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/remote_storage/example_write_adapter/server.go

This line

```
fmt.Printf("  %f %d\n", s.Value, s.Timestamp)
```

Prints this timestamp 1526415583412 and it's date is 9/3/50340
Which is impossible.
But if a remove three characters it works
1526415583

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus timestamps are in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.Second/time.Millisecond` to convert from `Milliseconds` to `Seconds`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(1526415583412/int64(time.Second/time.Millisecond),0))
}
```

Prints `2018-05-15 20:19:43 +0000 UTC`

Or, just divide by 1000.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(1526415583412/1000,0))
}
```